# Unable to get response using REST WebApi PutAsync when performing a chunked file upload

Tags: .net, rest, httpclient, asp.net-web-api

I'm working through writing my first REST web services (using the MVC 4 Beta and the swanky new Web Api), and I've got a problem when using the HttpClient.PutAsync method

Overview is that I am trying to write a file upload process, where I am chunking up the file and using the MVC 4 WebApi's HttpClient.PutAsync method. If I just loop through my chunks and call PutAsync, then everything is generally fine. However, occasionally the server is unable to write a specific chunk, and I need to get that failure reported back to the client so the chunk upload can be retried. I also need to have someway of knowing when the upload has completed, so the next stage in the upload step can execute (eg: once the file is uploaded, then there is a DB write that needs to happen, plus some additional processing needs to be kicked off on the server for creating preview images and the like).

The problem is that when I try and access the response from the PutAsync method, everything just falls into a screaming heap - the first chunk is sent by the client, but never received by the server, and the whole upload process grinds to a halt.

Here's the server code for handling the PutAsset method (I've stripped all the non-relevant code out for clarity). It seems to work fine - files can be happily uploaded and reassembled:

```
<HttpPut()>
Public Function PutArtwork(assetID As String, data As AssetBlock) As HttpResponseMessage(Of AssetBlockResponse)

    'Get the info from the tracker file
    Dim lContents As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(IO.Path.Combine(My.Settings.ServiceTempDirectory, "Asset/", (data.Tracker & ".tracker")))
    Dim lAssetInfo As AssetUpload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of AssetUpload)(lContents)

    If WriteChunkToFile(assetID, lAssetInfo, data) Then
        Dim lTracker As AssetBlockResponse = New AssetBlockResponse
        lTracker.TrackerGID = data.Tracker
        Return New HttpResponseMessage(Of AssetBlockResponse)(lTracker, HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
    Else
        tracker.TrackerGID = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
        tracker.ErrorCode = ApiErrorCode.FileChunkWriteFailed
        tracker.Message = String.Format("Write error for chunk {0-{1}", data.Offset, data.Length - 1)
        Dim lResponse As HttpResponseMessage(Of AssetBlockResponse) = New HttpResponseMessage(Of AssetBlockResponse)(tracker, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        lResponse.ReasonPhrase = String.Format("Write error for chunk {0-{1}", data.Offset, data.Length - 1)
        Return lResponse
    End If

End Function

Private Function WriteChunkToFile(assetID As String, info As AssetUpload, data As AssetBlock) As Boolean
    Dim lFile As String = GetAssetPath(assetID, String.Empty, data.Tracker & ".upload", 1, False, data.Length)
    If IO.File.Exists(lFile) Then
        Dim lBytes As Byte() = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data.FileData)
        Try
          WriteChunk(lFile, lBytes, data.Offset, data.Length)
          Return True
        Catch ex as Exception
          Return False
       End Try
End Function

Private Sub WriteChunk(filePath As String, data() As Byte, offset As Integer, length As Integer)
    Using lStream = IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)
        lStream.Position = offset
        lStream.Write(data, 0, length)
        lStream.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

And the client code calling the REST service :

```
Dim lClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient
Dim lBlock As AssetBlock = New AssetBlock

lBlock.Tracker = tracker.TrackerGID

lClient.BaseAddress = CreateUploadAddressUri(_BaseAddress, assetInfo)

Dim lLocalChunk As UploadChunkInfo
For Each chunkIterator As UploadChunkInfo In chunks
    lLocalChunk = chunkIterator
    lBlock.BlockHash = AssetMethods.SHA1HashBytes(lLocalChunk.Chunk)
    lBlock.Offset = lLocalChunk.Offset
    lBlock.Length = lLocalChunk.Chunk.Length
    lBlock.FileData = Convert.ToBase64String(lLocalChunk.Chunk)
    Dim lTask = lClient.PutAsync(lClient.BaseAddress, New StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lBlock), Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
Next
```

The above version works fine, but it is a fire and forget approach. What I wanted was to get the response back from the PutAsync, check to make sure that it all worked, and then move on to the next try, or retry the chunk as required. So the .PutAsync code above really needs to look like:

```
Dim lTask = lClient.PutAsync(lClient.BaseAddress, New StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lBlock), Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
If lTask.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode Then '!! This line is never hit !!
    lTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(Sub(readtask)
                                                            lLocalChunk.Status = UploadChunkInfo.ChunkUploadStatus.Uploaded
                                                        End Sub, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
Else
    lLocalChunk.Status = UploadChunkInfo.ChunkUploadStatus.Failed
    lLocalChunk.RetryCount += 1
End If
```

If the chunk is marked as failed, then we retry as part of the loop. Once we've retried a chunk X times, we regard the whole upload proess as a failure and report that back to the user. But executing the PutAsync with Result checking just stops the loop in it's tracks. It never even hits the server Put method. Fiddler shows no traffic to the server,

I'm completely out of ideas now - any thoughts?

Comment: Some additional info: I the file is small enough (less then the chunk size), then the PutAsync method seems to work fine, returning a response properly.

Comment: Wow.  You really don't need to do the chunking yourself.  HttpClient will do that for you.

Comment: It's async. You can't ask for .Result straight away. Put the checking inside a .ContinueWith, put all the tasks in an array, call [WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall.aspx) then go back and repost any that fail. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: The .ContinueWith was my problem - adding that into the mix when processing the task made everything work a treat (along with a spot of queuing so uploads could be easily rejected and rolled back). Thanks @DanF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that I have that tests the file uploading to a Web API

```
   [Fact]
        public void UploadAFile() {

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_HostUrl);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(typeof(SimpleApiController).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(typeof(SimpleApiController),"bigfile.pdf"));
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            var responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync("SimpleApi/SendBigFile", fileContent).Result;


            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseMessage.StatusCode);
            Assert.Equal("102061", responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
```

If you are doing self-host you will need to set the config like this on the server,

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(_HostUrl) {
                      TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.Streamed,
                      // Bypass 64K buffer in request body handler
                      MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 500,
                      MaxBufferSize = 1024 * 500
                  }; // Increase DOS protection limit
```

and the server side handler looks like

```
 public HttpResponseMessage SendBigFile() {

            var stream = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK); ;
            response.Content = new StringContent(memoryStream.Length.ToString());
            return response;

        }
```

Comment: What's that look like on the consuming side (inside the MVC4 webapi)? Do you get the file in one big blob in the controller, or in individual chunks? The code above looks neat.

Comment: I really like the look of this technique, but try as I might, it couldn't get it to work. It gave the impression of working, but always seemed to choke on the streaming eventually. I've filed it away to look at more closely when I've got some time (until then, my original issue has been resolved as above)